# Replacing variables in JSON with string text in Karate DSL

Tags: automation, karate

I have a json request body which contains string text where some variable value need to be replaced but there is no way directly through which it can be replaced in json.

Example:
`{ "key1":"#(var1)", "key2":"https://example.com/123/search" }`

I need to replace value 123 in key2, but if i am doing "https://example.com/"+"#(var2)"+"/search" it is not working out. Tried few other stuff but nothing working out in case of karate replace variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use JS:

```
* def body = { key2: 'https://example.com/123/search' }
* body.key2 = body.key2.replace('123', '456')
* match body == { key2: 'https://example.com/456/search' }
```

Comment: if i need to replace this variable in multiple keys of body the code will be repetitive with this approach.  I tried out with another approach of js and it worked. It is as following:

* string body = { key1: 'https://example.com/123/search', key2: 'https://example2.com/123/search'}
* body.replaceAll('123','456')